# Possible ways to choose 3 Kings and 2 other non-paired cards?

Tags: combinatorics

From a *standard deck* (52 cards, 4 suits) of playing cards, how many ways is it possible to be dealt *three kings* as a three of a kind? So the two other cards cannot be able to form a pair nor can they be another king as that would make it a four of a kind.

This is the answer I came up with, however, I feel like it is wrong. There is a possibility that this expression allows me to pick *any* three of a kind.

$$[C(13,1)\cdot C(4,3)] \cdot [C(12,2)\cdot C(4,1) \cdot C(4,1)]$$

To prevent such occurrences, would I have to divide the expression with "13!"? Or would I have to rewrite the expression in a completely new way? I might be overthinking this but I still feel like I am wrong.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First handle the king:$\binom{4}3$

and then choose $2$ cards out of the other denomination:$\binom{12}2$.

Choose the suit for the two cards: $4^2$.

Hence overall, $$\binom{4}3\binom{12}24^2=4^3\cdot \frac{12(11)}{2!}=(66)(64)=4224$$

Remark: There is no need to have $\binom{13}1$ since we already know we want that to be the king.

Comment: I see, since it is already established that I have to pick a king there is no need for C(13,1) as this would only make me choose 1 of the 13 possible ranks. Thank you very much!